# PHP strtotime not being executed at all within Joomla Component

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, joomla, strtotime

I am currently building a custom component within Joomla that takes values input from an input form and then wraps them up in order to be then sent off in a SOAP request.
One of the input form elements which is a date (date of birth, or it's name in the form "dob") needs to be converted to a valid date format which the SOAP api will accept.

I am having a very strange issue from within the function that accepts and prepares these form elements to be sent whereas the PHP function strtotime doesn't seem to be working at all when I attempt to change the date format to the valid format for the SOAP api to handle.

Here is the relevant function code that deals with the time formatting for the post element dob:

```
$postVar['dob'] = date("Y-d-m G-i-s", strtotime($_POST['dob']));
die(print_r($postVar['dob']));
```

When I die and print the variable as shown above to see what the result is, the strtotime is completely ignored and it doesn't die.

The form uses jQuery Datepicker for the date form element and here is what the variable output for $_POST['dob'] looks like when it is recieved by the function.

```
14/03/2013
```

Can anyone see why the strtotime function is not having any effect here and being ignored?
Thanks

Edit: Just to add here is the jQuery datepicker code if it is of any help.

```
jQuery("#dob").datepicker({dateFormat:'dd/mm/yy', changeMonth: true,    stepMonths: 12, showAnim:"slideDown" });
```

Comment: if it doesn't die when there's a `die()` statement there, then clearly it isn't running that section of code at all.

Comment: It's strange as if I take the strtotime out of the die it works correctly!

Comment: Maybe [DateTime (PHP 5.3+)](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) will work: `$dob = DateTime::createFromFormat('dd/mm/yy', $input->post->get('dob', '', 'string'));`.

Comment: No that doesn't seem to work either. could it be anytthing to do with the format jQuery Datepicker sends to the function?

Answer (score 2):

In Joomla!, you *never* touch any of the superglobals directly. Also, always check the results you get, if they may reflect an error condition.

```
$input          = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$dob            = $input->get('dob', null, 'string');
$postVar['dob'] = 'invalid';
if (!is_null($dob)) {
    $dob = strtotime($dob);
    if ($dob > 0) {
        $postVar['dob'] = date("Y-d-m G-i-s", $dob);
    }
}
```